# Is it possible to send Uri using AIDL?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, aidl

I have two apps, lets say AppClient and AppService. Those apps are communicating between each other using AIDL methods. Right now I would like to send Uri from AppClient to AppService in AIDL method parameter. I can send it without any problems but when I trying to open stream to read file
using

```
context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uriFile)
```

I'm getting SecurityException.
Permission Denial: opening provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{94e65ad 6186:com.app.service/u0a231} (pid=6186, uid=10231) that is not exported from uid 10043

In AppClient before sending Uri via AIDL method I'm granting required permissions first.

```
val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.app.client.fileprovider", fontFile)
grantUriPermission("com.app.service", uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION and Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
```

In documentation is see thet Uri is transported to other app using Intents but it I don't want to use Intents. It is possible to send Uri not using Intent e.g. in AIDL parameter ?

Comment: How exactly are you sending the uri? And what is AIDL?

Comment: Android Interface Definition Language, I'm passing Uri to AIDL method parameter so AppServie can receive this in Service via Binder Stub methods

Answer (score 0):

```
grantUriPermission("com.app.service", uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
```